# For loop mongoose returned data with javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, mongoose

As desired Mongoose returns the following data:

```
[Object]
0: Object
    thread_history: Array[12]
        0: Object
            __v: 0
            _id: "52c5be11be9931f90b000002"
            body: "thread message"
            uid: "maarten"
        __proto__: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
```

I emit this data using socket.io and then I try to convert the data to html.

Normally I would use the following for loop to convert the emitted data to html

```
socket.on('thread_history', function (thread_data) {
    if(thread_data.thread_history) {
    threads_log.push(thread_data);
        console.log(threads_log);
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < threads_log.length; i++) {
            html += '<div class="thread_wrapper">' + (threads_log[i].uid ? threads_log[i].uid : 'Server') + ' - ' + threads_log[i].body + '</div>';
        }
        thread_content.innerHTML = html;
        thread_content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight;
    }
    else {
        console.log("There is a problem: ", thread_data);
    }
});
```

Of course this doesn't work for the mongoose returned data.

I'm simply not able to access the objects, can someone assist me with this? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors in my console, however, there's 1 div created, containing "Server - undefined". So it probably fails there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery I came up with a really nice and clean solution.

```
  socket.on('thread_history', function (thread_data) {
        if(thread_data.thread_history) {
        threads_log.push(thread_data.thread_history);
            console.log(threads_log);
            var html = '';


            // jquery each the results
            $.each(thread_data.thread_history, function(){ 
                html += '<div class="thread_wrapper">' + this.uid + " - " + this.body + '</div>';
            });


            thread_content.innerHTML = html;
            thread_content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are looping through the wrong object, you are pushing "thread_data" and assuming to loop through "thread_data.thread_history".

Perhaps change line where you are pushing data to:

```
threads_log.push(thread_data.thread_history)
```

Otherwise if you need the whole `tread_data` in your log, inside your loop do:

```
threads_log[i].thread_history.body
```

Comment: Thanks, I have applied both your suggestions. I now get the array in my console and the following error: "Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined". So we're getting somewhere :) (seriously meant)

Comment: Please, don't apply both at the same time, use either one or the other

Comment: I did, but then I get the same as the beginning

Comment: Great, so if you get the array in your log then you are looping through the right thing. Now what do you get if you log your `threads_log[i]` in the loop?

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] - 0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
13: Object

Comment: Looks like you have 14 defined objects in array. So at which point do you get `undefined`?

Comment: at the body and uid values, so those values are inaccessible yet. The iteration is somehow wrong, but really can't see why. - edit: at none,  as far as I can see. No errors and the data within the objects is correct.

Comment: Do you get it at `i==0` ? Try adding check `if (typeof threads_log[i] != 'undefined') { ... }` around your html concatenation statement inside the loop. Hopefully this will catch the wrong value if it has creeped in somehow into the array.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Lex. I just came up with my own solution using jQuery. Thanks again :)